# Not able to connect to bolt in Neo4j through browser (deployed on AWS EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, neo4j, amazon-elb

I am not able to connect to Database through bolt in Neo4j browser when opening my domain on HTTPS. We are using Neo4j Enterprise version 4.4.4 and its deployed on AWS EC2. All the ports are opened in Security Group ( 7474, 7473, 7687, 22).

SSL has been applied through ACM and that is attached with Application Load Balancer.

Below is the error-
**ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use.**

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Have you opened access to external ports within the Neo4j config?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after deploying to EC2 using an AWS image (not from neo4j) to install neo4j community edition.

In my case, the neo4j browser was initially using this "Connect URL": `neo4j://127.0.0.1:7687`, which the browser then automatically changed to `bolt://127.0.0.1:7687`. After that, I saw the same error message that you did.

If you experience that scenario, you need to change the `127.0.0.1` portion of the URL to the appropriate public IP address or public DNS hostname for your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use "bolt+s://" or "neo4j+s://" for the connection
The '+s' variants of  URI schemes for encrypted sessions with full certificates
Refer to the [Neo4j Driver manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/4.0/client-applications/#driver-configuration-examples) for more details on the connection URI.